# Conflicting error in using c++ macro in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, macros, xcode6

We having problems regarding the usage of macro in project.
Below showing three files, debug.cpp and Utils.cpp are both using debug.h's macro function `AA(arg1, ...)`.

Three files have conflicts due to that macro definition.
When i comment out the line `void AaFun(const char *arg1, const char *arg2, ...);` in debug.h, debug.cpp can run but the Utils.cpp will show the error message of

> Use of undeclared identifier 'AaFun'.

But if we don't comment the line in debug.h, then we received the error message from debug.cpp

> Conflicting types for 'AaFun'

Three files should be able to run together, can anyone help me to understand the problem and a possible solution.

class debug.h:

```
#ifndef __DEBUG_H__
#define __DEBUG_H__

#define DEBUG 1

#ifdef DEBUG
#define AA(arg1, ...) AaFun(arg1, ARG2, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#endif

.....

void AaFun(const char *arg1, const char *arg2, ...);
```

class debug.cpp:

```
#include "debug.h"
...
void AaFun(const char *arg1, ...)
{
...function content...
}
```

class Utils.cpp

```
#include "debug.h"
string Utils::dupName(string origName, int num)
{
  AA("Making a dupName from %s and %d\n", origName.c_str(), num);

  return xxx;
}
```

Comment: That ifdef is always going to pass. You just defined it.

Comment: Your declaration and definition of `AaFun()` *are* different, so the compiler is right.  Also what is `ARG2` in the `AA` macro?

Comment: Sorry i can not understand what you mean. do you mean that i should add #ifdef DEBUG into debug.cpp?

Comment: No I mean you should make the declaration and definition of the `AaFun()` match.

Comment: I have include of debug.h in Utils.cpp, is that not enough?